# Activate virtual environment within Pydev

Tags: eclipse, virtualenv, pydev

I am confused about using the new virtual environments within `Pydev`. It appears that one must activate the virtual environment in a shell script first and then invoke `Eclipse` with `Pydev` from within the same shell script to get `Eclipse/Pydev` to use the virtual environment. Is there no way to activate a virtual environment from within Eclipse and thus control the execution environment from within `Eclipse`?

Answer (score 0):

What you're proposing does work, but it's not the ideal solution...

PyDev enables you to have multiple interpreters configured, so, my suggestion is that you configure one interpreter for each virtual environment you have and then use `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+I` to select the default (i.e.: current) one (although if you have multiple projects, and each depends on a different interpreter, you could also configure the interpreter to be used for a particular project in the project properties instead of switching the default each time).

Note that you can configure environment variables to be set to a particular interpreter if activating your interpreter does require some environment variable to be set (in the `Environment` tab in the interpreter configuration).

Comment: I may have 20 Eclipse projects for each virtual environment. I m strongly resistant to the idea of one virtual environment for each project.

Comment: I think you misread the answer (it says you should configure an interpreter for each virtual environment, not for each project)...